# Unable to get email body containing text or html content using Gmail Java API?

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to fetch the emails body using Gmail Java APIs. I am getting all the fields including `to, from, subject`.

But I am not able to get the textual body, also html body of email here is my code fragment :

```
 List<MessagePart> parts =  message.getPayload().getParts();
            StringBuilder textSb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder htmlSb = new StringBuilder();
            for (MessagePart part : parts) {
                if (part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {
                    try {
                        textSb.append(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(part.getBody().getData()), "UTF-8"));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/html")) {
                    try {
                        htmlSb.append(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(part.getBody().getData()), "UTF-8"));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

An short email body text-snippet can be obtained using below method ( But not full body ) :

```
message.getSnippet();
```

But thats not enough in my case I need whole body contents.

While iterating over `MessageParts` in above loop in debugger I am getting two parts first with MIME type `multipart/alternative` and other of MIME type `application/pdf` which is for pdf file attachment.

What should I do to get the body of email ?

Answer (score 1):

After searching more, I found that the details are in first part of the `MessageParts` List of `Message` object. In this first part you will get the List of `MessageParts` which contains the body of email i.e. textual content, html content :

```
    List<MessagePart> parts = message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getParts();
    StringBuilder mixContent = new StringBuilder();

    for (MessagePart part : parts) {
                    if (part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {
                        try {
                            mixContent.append(new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(part.getBody().getData()), "UTF-8"));
                            continue;
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/html")) {
                        try {
                             mixContent.append(new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(part.getBody().getData()), "UTF-8"));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```